# Piping a list of values to a bash script

Tags: bash, xargs, arguments

I have a script. `myScript`.

It takes two args. `myScript arg1 arg2`.

Let's say I have three sets of arguments.

```
argA1 argB1
argA2 argB2
argA3 argB3
```

Is there a way to pipe each line to myScript. I am open to having the set of args in a file, maybe use xargs. Not certain what to investigate.

So I would run command like faux example below:

```
cat myFile | xargs > myScript
```

Not to have another script, just commands on command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just:

```
xargs -l1 <myFile myScript
```

`-l1` tells `xargs` to run `myScript` once for each `1` `l`ine of input, with the words on that `1` `l`ine passed as separate arguments.

For `xargs`, words are separated with whitespace, and you can still have whitespace (even newlines) in a words by using quoting. Note however that while `xargs` supports `"..."`, `'...'` and `\` for quoting like most shells, its parsing is different from that of Bourne-like shells. In particular, there's no backslash processing in neither `"..."` nor `'...'` and only `\` can escape a newline.

For for instance, `myFile` could contain:

```
word1.1 word1.2
"word 2.1" 'word 2.2'
"word'3.1" 'word"3.2'
'word"'"4'1" word\"4\'2
'word '\
5.1 "word "\
5.2
```

And

```
xargs -l1 <myFile printf 'First word: "%s", second word: "%s"\n'
```

would produce:

```
First word: "word1.1", second word: "word1.2"
First word: "word 2.1", second word: "word 2.2"
First word: "word'3.1", second word: "word"3.2"
First word: "word"4'1", second word: "word"4'2"
First word: "word
5.1", second word: "word
5.2"
```

With the GNU implementation of `xargs`, you can improve it to:

```
xargs -l1 -r -a myFile myScript
```

Which has the benefit of leaving stdin alone and of not running `myScript` if `myFile` is empty.